# ASP.NET Populate ListView with Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'm trying to populate the ***ASP.NET LISTVIEW with Stored Procedure(@param1)***. Could anyone please let me know if it's possible at all. If it's possible, if show me few lines of code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Data Points: Data Source Controls in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163862.aspx) article on MSDN which nicely shows how to use the `SqlDataSource` in your web app to provide data to data-capable controls.

Basically, you need a SqlDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsYourData" Runat="server"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    ConnectionString="Server=(local);Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    SelectCommand="dbo.YourStoredProcName" 
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Param1" Type="String" />>
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

that defines where to connect to to get your data (to your stored proc) - here, you'll need to determine how to fill that parameter - in code? From another control on your ASP.NET page? Depending on that, you might use other elements into `<SelectParameters>`.

Once you have the data source, you can connect your list view to it:

```
<asp:ListView id="listView1" runat="server"
              DataSourceID="sdsYourData"
              DataTextField="SomeTextField" 
              DataValueField="YourIDField" />
```

Here, you need to set two fields:

- which of the columns from your SQL stored procedure will be used to display in the list view (`DataTextField`)?
- which of the columns from your SQL stored procedure will provide the value back to ASP.NET when that row in the listview is selected (`DataValueField`)?