# Listview databind confusion

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, stored-procedures

I currenty have a stored procedure that I am running and hoping to bind the data from the sp with my list view.  However, I am unsure of how to go upon doing this.

Here is my current code. I was thinking it was similar to databinding a gridview but got lost doing it.

HTML

```
<asp:ListView runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr style="background-color:green">
                                    <th><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkid" runat="server">Role ID</asp:LinkButton></th>
                                    <th><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdesc" runat="server">Role Description</asp:LinkButton></th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblroleid">Role ID</asp:Label></td>
                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblroledesc">Role Desc></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <tr style="background-color:Aqua">
                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblroleid">Role ID</asp:Label></td>
                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblroledesc">Role Desc</asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

c#

```
protected void roles()
    {
        txtSearch.Focus();
        string[] queryvalue = txtSearch.Text.Split(' ');
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rollup2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "USP_GET_USER_ROLES";
        cmd.Connection = myconn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = queryvalue[0].ToString();
        myconn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds);




        myconn.Close();
        myconn.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I do not have one.  Was not aware that the list view needed an id.  Just thought the information was bounded to rows and so the rows would of needed it instead.  I have very limited knowledge on listviews

Comment: Looks like you have very limited knowledge of ASP.NET. Googling for "ASP.NET data-driven controls"

Comment: Yeah I know I have a limited knowledge.  It also doesnot help that alot of the tutorials on list view databinding is just pulling information in from a database with no parameters.  I have yet to find one that shows this method which is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you out

[ASP.NET Populate ListView with Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196300/asp-net-populate-listview-with-stored-procedure)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsYourData" Runat="server"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    ConnectionString="Server=(local);Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    SelectCommand="dbo.YourStoredProcName" 
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Param1" Type="String" />>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```